# Faking navigation to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm not sure if the title of this question is clear enough (in fact, i'm pretty sure it isn't!) so let me explain what i'm trying to do:

I have a single view application and in that view is a tableview.

When I click on a cell in the tableview, I want the details in the view to change (the actual data/content will change but it will be the same view) and for it to look like there has been a navigation with a transition animation (preferably like a push).

There won't actually be a transition to a new view. It will just be a content refresh and an animation.

What is the best approach to take here? I don't want to hack something together that ends up haemorrhaging memory needlessly!

Comment: as your question title your question detail also is not clear so please explain more why you do not want another view controller and if possible explain it with images( screenshot or just a draw in paint)

Comment: "I don't want to hack something together" -> The design feels like a hack so the implementation probably will too. What is stopping you using a new view controller?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a very intuitive UI. If the data just updates on the table view, why pretend you have navigated away? Maybe look at [UITableViewRowAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadSections:withRowAnimation:)

Comment: As described, there does not appear to be a compelling reason _not_ to actually navigate to a new view controller. Between transitions and animations, doing things the right way should in no way limit what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Fair comments guys. I didn't want to just explain everything I wanted and get people to explain everything I needed to do but I clearly didn't  give you enough info to point me in the right direction so let me explain more: the view will have few fields at top + a table view on the bottom. The items in the table will be 'children' of the parent item that you are currently looking at. Tapping a cell should take you to the detail view of this 'child' data. They aren't actually children, they're related pieces of info so there could be an infinite number hence not wanting views on the storyboard

Comment: @mattt I've only just noticed your post (you must have posted as I was adding my comment by the looks of it - i was replying via the mobile app and didn't spot it). Now that i've added more detail, can you see why I can't have a navigation between two views? It would be infinite so I don't know how to get that on a storyboard :S ?!?!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i can not write code for now but here is logic , You have to change `datasource` of `UITableView` and set a flag like `isDetaialShowing`. In First view controller flag will be `NO` and you can load `cell1`. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` change this flag to `YES` and load `cell2`. You can change the objects to display. You may have a temp Array and transverse the objects.
Dont forget to `reloadTableview`

Comment: Hi @iAhmed , thanks for posting an answer. I've only just spotted it. Now that I have added more detail to the thread of comments, do you think its clearer what i'm looking for? I'm not sure if your suggestion was just for reloading a tableview with different data. I can get fields and a table view to load data but I want it to look like the user has navigated to another view (like you typically would if you clicked on a table view cell)

Comment: [UIView  beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
   [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
   
   [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
   [UIView commitAnimations];